# IE displays its conditional comments error

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, html, conditional-statements

Has anyone else had this problem?  I can find absolutely nothing when I search for an answer.  I have a conditional comment in my html to only display a flash file when the browser is IE.  And it works great, except that the conditional comment is displaying in my browser!  Please refer to the page:  http://htest.cloudmedia.biz/demo/demo.html to see the error (it only shows in IE).  Could it be because I haven't declared the page as an html4 page?  The only way I can get the comments to go away is if I use this syntax:        `<!--<![if lt IE10]><!-->my code<!--<![endif]-->`          .  When I do this, of course my flash file shows underneath my alternate content on other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have a space missing. The conditional should look like this:

```
[if lt IE 10]
```

Comment: Wow, I was racking my brain over this.  Simple, stupid mistake.  Thanks!